# Notepad++ Command Line Arguments

Tags: notepad++

Is there anywhere I can go to get a list of all Command Line arguments for Notepad++?
I am using Notepad++ 7.5.1 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The user manual seems to be pretty complete.

https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/command-prompt/

It also suggests you can run:

```
notepad++ --help
```